# Простое отображение таблицы WPF

Tags: wpf

Добрый день.
У меня задача: используя C#, WPF в инструментальной среде разработки MS Visual Studio отобразить таблицу максимально просто, с использованием разных цветов.

Сам я привык к SharpDevelop. там это делается элементарно. Думал в WPF все так-же но, похоже, ошибся. А нужно именно в WPF.

Comment: А в чем именно проблема?

Comment: Ну в WPF есть контрол DataGrid, чем он не подошел? Или проблема с привязкой данных?

Comment: А чем отличается код для случая SharpDevelop то кода для случая VisualSudio?